# Будет ли "разбить палатку" сказуемым в синтаксическом разборе?

Tags: синтаксис

1. Разбить палатку — сказуемое.
2. Разбить — сказуемое, палатку — дополнение.

Как правильно?

Answer (score 3):

Выражение РАЗБИТЬ ПАЛАТКУ (изначально *разбить лагерь*) стало устойчивым. Поэтому всё выражение является одним членом предложения.

Придётся уточнить свою позицию.

Разбить палатку, если подходить строго,  вообще-то невозможно. Её можно установить. Разбить (разделить на части) можно парк, сквер, лагерь, то есть то, что требует какой-то  планировки, расположения частей в определённом порядке. Выражение *разбить палатку* появилось под влиянием выражения *разбить палаточный лагерь*.

Но не совсем правильное сочетание *разбить палатку* в современном языке закрепилось, оно стало устойчивым. Устойчивые выражения являются одним членом предложения. А вот выражение *разбить сквер* надо дробить, потому что сквер действительно разбивают. *Сквер* - дополнение.

Кто-то думает иначе. Пожалуйста! Я выразила свою точку зрения на проблему.

Comment: Оно, конечно, так... да только устойчиво оно с оговорками... см. мой готовящийся ответ

Comment: Кузнецов не видит разницу в значениях для "разбить палатку" и "разбить сквер". Вот в чем фокус. А так-то вы правы целиком, не надо ничего уточнять. Можно предположить, что Кузнецов не возводит "разбить" в данном значении к "разделить на части". Если аргументированной опровергнуть его в этом, то к его мнению можно и не прислушаться...

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, в целом Екатерина права. "Разбить" в этом значении можно весьма ограниченный круг объектов, причем значение это очень далеко от основных значений глагола "разбить". Это признак устойчивого выражения, фразеологизма, даже идиомы. Такие конструкции не членятся на составляющие при грамматическом разборе. Отсюда и толкование "разбить палатку" - фразеологическое сказуемое.

Но можно возразить, что выражение уже находится в стадии "деидеомизации", словари уже фиксируют это самостоятельное значение для "разбить".
8. что. Устроить, соорудить; расположить. Р. грядки. Р. парк. Р. лагерь. Р. палатку.
(БТС Кузнецова).

Насколько понимаю, в этом и причина сомнений.

Как тут поступить, я не знаю. Вернее всего - для школьных нужд особенно - стоит упростить ситуацию и разбирать по наиболее простому пути, то есть выделять сказуемое+дополнение, а академическую трактовку можно упомянуть как факультативную и дискуссионную.
Как-то так.

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ!